# Node JS exec doesn't callback if exec an exe

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following exec command in a Node JS application that launches an EXE:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var theApp = 'HelloWorld';

var theCommand = 'C:/Program Files/' + theApp + '/dist/' + theApp + '-win32/' + theApp + '.exe';

exec(theCommand, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('command callback');
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

The EXE is launched fine, but none of the console logs are fired inside of the exec command, so it's as though calling an exe doesn't cause a callback to be fired. If I exec another Node app, e.g. `node app.js` then it fires the callback! So it's because I'm calling an EXE to be opened!

How can I solve this?

Comment: [The documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) states that the callback will only run after the process terminates. Can you confirm this is the case here?

Comment: @blgt I'm not sure, is there a way to ensure the process terminates?

Comment: In fact! Wouldn't terminating the process mean that the EXE I've just called has been closed? Which isn't what I want.

Comment: @Cameron Well, the callback will only be executed once the process terminates which means that the application ("exe") has been closed.

Comment: How could I run the command and get a callback ONCE the app has been executed? I don't have control of the other EXE so can't fire any events from that to say it has opened. Or is this not possible?

Comment: What is `exec`?  Is it `child_process.exec`?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, sorry should of stated that.

Comment: I suspect you have an error happening somehow because when I run a simple version of your script that just does `"copy sample.txt sample.new"`  it works just fine and the callback is called right when the copy finishes.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes it does for other commands just not EXE because the callback only fires when the app closes and completes the process.

Comment: Are you saying that your `.exe` does not exit?  If so, then either remove your question or write an answer to your own question.

Comment: @jfriend00 The problem is how to get a callback to fire when you exec an exe from NodeJS as it currently requires the EXE to be called and closed to call it, which isn't what I want! So why would I remove the question???

Comment: I don't understand at all what your problem is or what you are still asking for help with.  A node.js app can run and exit by itself just fine.  Some don't because they start a server and keep running.  Some exit just fine when they are done with their work.  What is your actual question then?  incidentally, none of this has to do with your program being an EXE like your question seems to think.  It only has to do with whether the program runs and exits or keeps running indefinitely.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm not calling a Node JS application. I'm calling another EXE from Node JS. For example I could open `Word.exe` but because `exec` in Node JS only fires the callback on the process termination, it doesn't fire until the application you have opened is closed, but I don't want that.

Comment: Well, that's the way it works.  So, there's no answer here other than "that's the way it works".  You can check for an immediate error and if, no immediate error and no immediate termination, then the program is running.  That's how it works.

Comment: @jfriend00 So you're saying it's not possible to fire a callback in Node JS when you open another EXE that doesn't close straight away?

Comment: FYI, if the program runs and does not exit right away, when do you want a callback?  There's no specific event in the lifetime of the program.  It's running indefinitely.  What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: I want to know the application has been opened and the command has successfully run. It may take x amount of seconds for the command to complete and launch the application, so I don't want my callback to fire until then.

Comment: There is no such a generic event.  Because the program you run can literally be doing anything, there is no standard way to know it's done starting up and is now successfully started.  I will write an answer that gives you some options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the program you are running starts up and does not terminate, you will not get any sort of callback or event until the program eventually exits.  The system simply does not define any sort of event for that condition.  A child process is either running or not.  For any further detail about its condition, you are expected to communicate with it in some way (stdin, stdout, stderr, connect socket to it, interrogate the process in the system, etc...)

Since the program can literally be doing anything, all you can know from the outside is whether it exited quickly with an error or exited quickly with no error or whether it appears to be still running.  The return value from the `exec()` call contains a process ID so you can also query some info about that process ID if there's something specifically you want to know.

Here's an example of what you could do:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var theCommand = "notepad sample.txt";

function runit(cmd, timeout) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var ch = exec(theCommand, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve("program exited without an error");
            }
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve("program still running");
        }, timeout);
    });
}

runit(theCommand, 1000).then(function(data) {
    console.log("success: ", data);
}, function(err) {
    console.log("fail: ", err);
});
```

It isn't clear to me which way you want it to act if the program you're running exits quickly, but without an error (the first call to `resolve()` in the code).  You could change that to a `reject()` depending upon behavior what you want.  I assumed that an exit without an error was not an error, but your situation might be different.

Note: if you aren't actually waiting for the completion of the other program, you may not want to use `.exec()` since that is part of what it is built for.  You may want to use one of the other child process creation methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time to provide this answer. I was thinking of doing a timeout myself... but looks like you have a much nicer implementation that handles a few scenarios.

Comment: You mention that I could use another creation method... which one could I use if I don't want to wait for the completion? Thanks

Comment: @Cameron - `.spawn()` is more commonly used for long running processes because you can get intermediate results via the stdout or stderr streams that are available from the beginning with `.spawn()`.  You can read a bit about the difference between spawn and exec [here](http://www.hacksparrow.com/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child_process.html) and [here](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Nodejs-managing-child-processes-starting-stopping-exec-spawn).